# How to do post hoc comparisons after a repeated measures ANOVA in R

Tags: statistics, modelling, graphs, lme4

I have a data set of several samples with their expression of proteins, in response to four different doses of a drug and two genotypes. I have been able to generate the two-way ANOVA using ezANOVA but I am having difficulty in generating multiple comparisons results. In GraphPad, I am able to compare means of each group to the control, the 0 dose, within each genotype and apply a Dunnett's correction. However, I am trying to implement this in R and my significant values are not lining up with GraphPad. I am using, emmeans and lme4 package to try generate these multiple comparisons. Any ideas or other readings to try? Thanks.

The code for how I'm generating the anova results below

```
library(ez)
ezANOVA(data = data_long, 
                         dv = .(Expression), 
                         wid = .(Subject), 
                         within = .(Dose), 
                         between = .(Genotype),
                         type = 3, 
                         detailed = TRUE,
                         return_aov = TRUE)
```

Then the code I used to generate the Dunnett's Test

```
library(DescTools)

DunnettTest(data_long$Expression, data_long$Genotype)
```

However the output of the Dunnett's test only compares from the Genotype and not the dosages within each Genotype at each dose.

The output in R
[image]

The output in GraphPad
[image]

I've tried switching from Genotype to Dose, but it doesn't separate the pairs by Genotype.